# Align text vertically in a card (Vuetify)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I want to align some text vertically to a card using Vuetify or regular CSS on Vue:

[image]

**My code**:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <v-container class="my-5">

      <v-row justify="space-between">

        <v-col cols="12" md="6" lg="3">
           <v-btn outline block class="primary">1</v-btn>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="12" md="6" lg="3">
           <v-btn outline block class="primary">1</v-btn>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="12" md="6" lg="3">
           <v-card outlined color="red" height="450">
             <p class="mx-3 text-center">texto textinho texto textao texto bla bla bla pi popopopo blabla bleuu bli pei pou</p>
           </v-card>
        </v-col>

      </v-row>

    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You mean you want every other word on a new line centered in the middle?

Comment: I want to align the text in this red card, vertically. I tried to use lots of vuetify params at v-card and v-col, but no one Works:/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[flex align](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-align)** provided by vuetify, add to your card tag `d-flex align-center`:

```
<v-card outlined color="red" height="450" class="d-flex align-center">
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/XWXbKgN)**